# How to slow down and optimize fluid animation for a collision animation

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, fluid-simulation, geometry

I have a scene where a fluid flow object(a plane) is emitting fluids which is then affecting the main object. I am trying to animate the entire scene, but the animation is so fast I can hardly catch it, here is a example:

[image]

Here are the settings for the domain, flow(plane), and effector(main object) for the fluid sim:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The tutorial is not precise in explaining all the small steps, but here is the result I am looking for:

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DbewtqTrzgo&t=323s Here is the tutorial for reference

Comment: I think a lot of the animation frames and settings are missing in the tutorial where a smooth flow of fluids is observed, that might be the issue causing in my blend file